# How do I set up a multi-stage test pipeline in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

Specifically, for a Scalatra project, but the question probably applies to most.

For example, I typically want to run:

- unit tests
- code quality checks (coverage, duplication, complexity, jsLint!)
- integration tests (not too many!)
- acceptance tests (usually a "pre-checkin" subset)
- regression tests (basically the same as acceptance tests, but a bigger set)
- performance tests

I want to run different subsets of these by context - i.e. after a simple code change I might just run the first three; before checking in I might want to run a bigger set, and the Continuous Integration server might have a "fast" and a "slow" build that have even bigger sets.

The basic sbt docs seem to assume a single "test" target - is there a recommended way to implement multiple test phases like this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this blog about using integrated testing with SBT and Hudson:

http://henkelmann.eu/2010/11/14/sbt_hudson_with_test_integration

Then, to add your own actions you can use this page:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/CustomActions

Basically, though, you will probably want to add a new action for each of your testing steps, in order to get the particular events you want to happen.